# Limit the number of results while fetching from a folder using GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl() method in sharepoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer, office365apis

Currently I am performing a REST API call to fetch files and folders from a particular folder path(serverRelativeUrl) in Sharepoint online 2013.

```
https://nextlabs.sharepoint.com/sites/vignesh/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/')?$expand=Folders,Files
```

How to set or limit the number of items to be fetched? 
I have tried below two ways but it did not work.

```
https://nextlabs.sharepoint.com/sites/vignesh/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/')?$expand=Folders,Files&$limit=2

https://nextlabs.sharepoint.com/sites/vignesh/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/')?$expand=Folders,Files&$top=2
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

`$limit` and `$top` query options could be applied only for a collection of entries such as `FolderCollection` resource ([Top System Query Option](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#TopSystemQueryOption)), for example:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<url>')/Folders?$top=2 //working
```

but **not** for a *single* resource like `Folder` in your example:

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<url>')?$top=2  //not working
```

I guess your goal is to retrieve a limited number of files and folders from a list/library, right? If so, I would suggest to convert your query to the following one:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Shared Documents')/items?$select=File,Folder&$expand=Folder,File&$top=2
```